# org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse sku_str

Tags: solr

See below error:

> "error": {
>       "msg": "org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse 'sku_str:VFY:A5440M35A5ME': Encountered \" \":\" \": \"\" at line 1,
>   column 11.
>
> code": 400   }

Comment: It does not like the colon in the value, try sku_str:"VFY:A..." instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape solr query string , See below function

SolrUtils::escapeQueryChars — Escapes a lucene query string

http://php.net/manual/en/solrutils.escapequerychars.php